# Lines come up in rendering after adding hair

Tags: materials, particles, hair

I made a few color changes to this model and added hair. Now, there are some strange lines showing up in my render.

The material of the head is a mix of *translucent BSDF*, *glossy BSDF* and two *subsurface scattering* nodes. The hair is using the same material as the head. It is set for 1500 samples and took around two hours to reach 60%. At that point, the lines became a major concern for me and I starting searching for possible reasons though I have not found any yet. So, what are these lines and how can I get rid of them?

I am using CPU rendering but i don't think that could be the cause of it as the problem is with the hair Also I am using blender 2.77

.blend files:

[image]

node setup
[image]

before
[image]

Here is a picture after adding adding the hair 
 [image: head with lines]

Comment: Perhaps you would consider [uploading](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) your .blend? It may be helpful to also see your particle and render settings.

Comment: In addition to your Blend file, a screenshot of your node setup, hair system settings, and render settings would also be helpful (for those of us checking from work... where we don't use Blender ;-) )

Comment: I wonder if this could be a GPU problem. Are you using GPU render? What kind of CPU or GPU are you rendering with? (Please add it to the question).

Comment: @Matt I have added the blend file though it won't allow me to add any more pics as I have less reputation but I will put all that in a shared folder in my google drive and put a link here

Comment: @AbhishekSaxena, you can combine multiple images with GIMP or similar to add more than one when necessary. This would be preferable so that people don't have to download them or follow links.

Comment: @AbhishekSaxena You can just add links to extra images to your question and someone with enough reputation will convert them to images.

Comment: @Timaroberts i thought about that but that would make the image more than 2 MB (as it would be a  lot of images ) or reduce the quality of each image still i'll try to combine the images

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the dropdown menu in *Hair BSDF* from *Reflection* to *Transmition*. This helped when I downloaded the .blend file.

You could also try lowering the samples, as you said the problem only appeared when the count got up high. In the image rendering from the .blend file, noticable changes stop around 300-400 samples. More than 250, in general, just makes you feel better without actually changing anything.

Hope this helps and happy Blending!

Comment: your answer reduced the lines but they are still there also the sampling was that high because i was trying to get rid of the noise as  _subsurface scattering_  nodes creates a lot of noise even without the hair